# How do I place an image between two rows of Visual Composer?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, visual-composer

I am new to WordPress and is currently using visual composer to build websites. While building a mobile app landing page, I am facing troubles while placing a png image between two rows. Please refer the below image -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/arJx1.jpg

The above image shows a phone which is placed in the gray row but is slightly moved up to position it between its original row and the row above it.

Please help me achieve this effect. I tried adding negative top-margin, padding but nothing seems to give the exact effect.

Comment: Voting to close, as it does not include a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) per site guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the site I made the same, hope it will help you : http://utplanning.com/